# I have a question about regexp pattern matching for java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to know the cause of regexp not working properly.

```
public static void run() {
    Scanner strInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String number = strInput.nextLine();
    if(getType(number)) {
       System.out.println("good");
    } else {
       System.out.println("");
    }
}

//regExp
public static boolean getType(String word) {
    return Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$", word); //Q1, Q2
}
```

for example,,

Q1. `Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$", word);`
desired answer (input) : a+C+a+2+3 -> false

Q2. `Pattern.matches("^[0-9|*|+|/|-]*$", word);`
desired answer (input) :  1+2/33*4 -> true , 123+333 -> true

Sorry,, Please understand that I am not good at English because I am foreigner..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `^[a-zA-Z]*$`  Match at least 0 or more of lowercase/uppercase **letters** from beginning to the end.  `a+C+a+2+3` does not satisfy  those requirements but an empty string does.
- `^[0-9|*|+|/|-]*$` Match at least 0 or more of **digits**, `*`,  `+`, `/` or `-` from beginning to the end; thus will match `1+2/33*4` and an empty string too.

So, this might be the pattern you're looking for:

```java
public static boolean getType(String word) {
    //Match at least 1 or more digits, *, /, +, - from beginning to the end.
    return word.matches("^[0-9*\\/+-]+$"));
    //This one is even better though. "+1", "1+", will not match
    //return word.matches("^([0-9]+[*\\/+-])+[0-9]+$"));
}
```